How to create chart in power apps which shows number of post done by team member in teams channel?
I want to create one chart which shows number of post by each team member in the channel. I am using power apps in teams. Chart should have number of post on y-axis and name of person on x-axis.

Can you share structure of your current data?


In the Data tab of Power Apps, add the Microsoft Teams connector
In the OnVisible property of your Screen control which has the chart, paste the following code:

// Get Team's groupId
UpdateContext(
    {
        varGroupId: LookUp(
            MicrosoftTeams.GetAllTeams().value,
            displayName = "Your Team's display name"
        ).id
    }
);

// Get Team's channelId
UpdateContext(
    {
        varChannelId: LookUp(
            MicrosoftTeams.GetChannelsForGroup(varGroupId).value,
            displayName = "Your channel's display name"
        ).id
    }
);

// Get all messages from channel
ClearCollect(
    RawChannelMessages,
    MicrosoftTeams.GetMessagesFromChannel(
        varGroupId,
        varChannelId
    ).value
);

// Get all distinct users from channel messages, init MessageCount column
ClearCollect(
    DistinctUsers,
    AddColumns(
        Filter(
            Distinct(
                RawChannelMessages,
                from.user.displayName
            ),
            !IsBlank(ThisRecord.Value)
        ),
        MessageCount,
        0
    )
);

// Update distinct user list with their message counts
ForAll(
    RawChannelMessages,
    With(
        {messageUserDisplayName: ThisRecord.from.user.displayName},
        With(
            {
                existingUser: LookUp(
                    DistinctUsers,
                    Value = messageUserDisplayName
                ),
                existingUserMessageCount: LookUp(
                    DistinctUsers,
                    Value = messageUserDisplayName
                ).MessageCount
            },
            Patch(
                DistinctUsers,
                existingUser,
                {MessageCount: existingUserMessageCount + 1}
            )
        )
    )
);

Note: Be sure to change Your Team's display name and Your channel's display name to their respective values.
This will create a table called DistinctUsers which has two columns. Value, which is the name of all distinct users who have made posts in your channel. MessageCount, which is the number of posts each distinct user has posted.
Here is an example of DistinctUsers:
MessageCount | Value
1            | Jon, Doe
3            | Al, Dente
2            | First, Last


In your Chart control, set the chart's Items property to
DistinctUsers
You might need to save and refresh your app to see results


Thanks for responding, I tried to put your code to onselect property of graph and put Items as DistinctUsers. But not getting bars in the chart. please let me know, What I doing wrong.

The code should be put into the OnVisible property of your screen. You will likely need to save and refresh your app after that to see results. I was in a rush last night so I've updated my original answer to be more descriptive. Please let me know if you have any problems

In screen Controls, There is no option 'OnVisible'  in property drop down in Columnchart. There only one option starting with 'On' is Onselect. Is there other options which I can use ?

You are correct, the ColumnChart control does not have an OnVisible property. The screen control is the one with the OnVisible property. On the left side of your browser you will see a list of all your controls in a Tree View. In the Tree View, click the screen control which your ColumnChart control is under, then look for the OnVisible property. If you have only one screen and have not renamed it, it is likely called "Screen1"

Thank you so much beelow. It working correctly.
